# Fixed term is "(Intercept)" --Dredge function

Tags: regression, logistic, aic, lme4-nlme

I'm currently building a glmer model for a resource selection analysis. See code below:

```
results<-glmer(R0A1~scale(Dist_MP)+scale(Dist_MPHW)+scale(Dist_HW)+scale(Dist_YP)+ 
                 scale(Dist_AG)+scale(Dist_Shrub)+scale(Dist_CountyRoad)+
                 scale(Dist_PrimaryRoad)+scale(Dist_SecondaryRoad)+scale(Dist_TertFireRoad)+
                 (1|ID)+(1|Year_),data=secondorder,family=binomial)
```

I attempted the following function:

```
aicc<-dredge(results,eval=TRUE,rank="AICc")
```

However, I receive the following error message:

```
Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
```

I'm not totally sure what this referring to and would appreciate any input.

Comment: `dredge` is not a command in base R. At a minimum, we'll need to know what package it comes from.

Comment: @user777...the package is MuMIn. See cran document: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf